# integrating an infinite series of functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I got stuck trying to resolve the following:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\int\limits_{(0,1)}|nx^{n-1}-\left(n+1\right)x^n|d\mu=\infty$$

With $x\in\left(0,1\right)$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$My current approach is to resolve the inner integral, so

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\int\limits_{(0,1)}|nx^{n-1}-\left(n+1\right)x^n|d\mu=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\int\limits_{(0,1)}|x^n\left(n\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)-1\right)|d\mu=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\int\limits_{(0,1)}|x^n||\left(n\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)-1\right)|d\mu$$

Because $x^n$ is going to be always a positive number I can omit the absolute value, on the other hand $\frac{1}{x}-1$ is always positive in the domain of definition, and because $n$ is always positive the product $n\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)$ is always positive, the problem is that the positiveness of $n\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)-1$ depends on the value of $n$, because it is negative in the first 20 or so values, after that, if $x\in(0,1)$ is always positive, and I don't know how to write this, because the series is the outmost operation, should I just sum take the integral directly and consider the series only when $n>20$? I'll be off but at the limit would that error matter? Any pointer would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I do not understand the "20 thing". It doesn't matter what the value of $n$ is, if $x$ is sufficiently close to $1$ then $n(\frac{1}{x}-1)-1$ is close to $-1$ and in particular negative...

Comment: Hint: write $nx^{n-1}-\left(n+1\right)x^n=x^{n-1}(n-(n+1)x)$, determine where this expression is + and where it is -, and split the integral accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$It is easier to argue as follows. $nx^{n-1}\ge(n+1)x^n$, for nonnegative $x,n$, if and only if $\frac{n}{n+1}\ge x$. So the integral should read as: $$\int_0^{n/(n+1)}[nx^{n-1}-(n+1)x^n]\d x+\int_{n/(n+1)}^1[(n+1)x^n-nx^{n-1}]\d x$$And you can evaluate this to be: $$\frac{2}{n+1}\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}$$We know that $(1+1/n)^n<e$ and thus $(1+1/n)^{-n}>1/e$ for all natural $n$, so it follows that: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^1|nx^{n-1}-(n+1)x^n|\d x>\frac{2}{e}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n+1}$$Which famously diverges.

Comment: Thanks @FShrike, that partition was the missing piece